# OOM error even when i decode image

Tags: android, android-imageview

Im having issues loading an image onto the screen of certain devices.

All the screen has is one image, but its quite a tall image.

Below are the image dimensions

Portrait:

- mdpi: 360x1074
- hdpi: 540x1611
- xhdpi: 720x2148
- xxhdpi: 1080x3142

Landscape:

- mdpi: 640x705
- hdpi: 960x1058
- xhdpi: 1280x1410
- xxhdpi: 1920x1035

I have followed: https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html also this http://successmatics.com/blog/loading-large-bitmaps-in-android-ui/ but they basically the same.

If I load a much smaller image say a thumbnail of something else, it loads fine.

Loading the image in the oncreate

```
mImageView.setImageBitmap(
   ImageUtils.decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(),
   R.drawable.image,
   ImageUtils.getScreenWidth(getApplicationContext()),
   ImageUtils.getScreenHeight(getApplicationContext())));
}
```

Methods used to decode image (from the 2 urls above)

```
  public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
  }

  public static int calculateInSampleSize(
          BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

      final int halfHeight = height / 2;
      final int halfWidth = width / 2;

      // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
      // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
      while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) >= reqHeight
              && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) >= reqWidth) {
//--------i tried a sample size of 2. was hoping 3 would work---------//
        inSampleSize *= 3;
      }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
  }

  public static int getScreenWidth(Context context) {
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    return displayMetrics.widthPixels;
  }

  public static int getScreenHeight(Context context) {
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    return displayMetrics.heightPixels;
  }
```

Does anyone have a better way of decoding large images so I dont get the OOM

or

there is something wrong with my code (which is from android themselves)

EDIT: Sorry forgot the stacktrace:

```
E/dalvikvm-heap: Out of memory on a 10391232-byte allocation.
    I/dalvikvm: "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
    I/dalvikvm:   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0xb264b450 self=0xb8d604e0
    I/dalvikvm:   | sysTid=26630 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[fopen-error:2] handle=-1216986048
    I/dalvikvm:   | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=117 stm=69 core=0
    I/dalvikvm:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
    I/dalvikvm:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:500)
    I/dalvikvm:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:353)
    I/dalvikvm:     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:781)
    I/dalvikvm:     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1935)
    I/dalvikvm:     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
    I/dalvikvm:     at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:120)
    I/dalvikvm:     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:57)
    I/dalvikvm:     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:53)
    I/dalvikvm:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:106)
    I/dalvikvm:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:980)
    I/dalvikvm:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1039)
    I/dalvikvm:     at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
    I/dalvikvm:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:675)
    I/dalvikvm:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
    I/dalvikvm:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
    I/dalvikvm:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
    I/dalvikvm:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
    I/dalvikvm:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
    I/dalvikvm:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
    I/dalvikvm:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280)
    I/dalvikvm:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
    I/dalvikvm:     at com.myapp.app.item.protection.Protection.onCreate(Protection.java:31)
    I/dalvikvm:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
    I/dalvikvm:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
    I/dalvikvm:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
    I/dalvikvm:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
    I/dalvikvm:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
    I/dalvikvm:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
    I/dalvikvm:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    I/dalvikvm:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    I/dalvikvm:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
    I/dalvikvm:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    I/dalvikvm:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    I/dalvikvm:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
    I/dalvikvm:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    I/dalvikvm:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The only image loading library I am using at the moment is Volley for networked images. This is resource in the @Drawable file. There are 2 version, Portrait and landscape (Don't want stretching)

Thanks

Comment: post your logcat ?? are you using any library for image loading?

Comment: please see edit

Answer (score 0):

replace this line

```
options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);
```

with

it will solved your problem

```
options.inSampleSize = 8;
```

Comment: that kind of works, except the image is now squashed near the top of the activity?

Comment: Yes because inSampleSize  returning a smaller image to save memory hence, Quality will be slide down

Comment: Is there a way to have it still display at the same size but at a slightly lower quality?

Comment: @x10sion there is another optimized way where you can get Proper image with reduced size https://gist.github.com/vipulasri/0cd97d012934531f1266 refer this link

Comment: do you have an example of this ImageCompress class being used?

Comment: the gist mentioned by Mohit is the example

Answer (score 0):

here is the method i usually use for calculating **inSampleSize**

```
private int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options opts, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    int outHeight = opts.outHeight;
    int outWidth = opts.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;
    while (outHeight > reqHeight || outWidth > reqWidth) {
        outHeight /= 2;
        outWidth /= 2;
        inSampleSize *= 2;
    }
    return inSampleSize;
}
```

if you want your bitmap fit for your ImageView, you can use the scaleType in xml like:

```
<ImageView
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:id="@+id/test_iv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

If you dont want to decode image yourself, you might want to use some third part library like [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

Comment: Is there a way to have it still display at the same size but at a slightly lower quality because my image goes off the screen as its quite a long image

Answer (score 0):

> There is something wrong with my code (which is from android
>   themselves)

Its not wrong(in a sense it isn't malfunctioning). its doing what is stated.

> Does anyone have a better way of decoding large images so I dont get
>   the OOM

Ammm.. i do not, but i can show you where you can make changes to make this work.

There is a problem with the condition you used to calculate down-sample index. i will explain it with example given by in your question.

```
Configuration landscape

XXHDPI qhd device with dimention 960x540 hence,

    deviceWidth 960  deviceHeight 540 
    halfWidth 960    halfHeight 517  
    imgWidth 1920    imgHeight 1035
```

Device width is the required width here so,

```
reqWidth 960  reqHeight 540
```

The Condition you used is

```
 while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) >= reqHeight
              && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) >= reqWidth) {
//--------i tried a sample size of 2. was hoping 3 would work---------//
        inSampleSize *= 3;
      }
```

If we simply set the parameter it becomes

```
while ((517 / 1) >= 540
              && (960 / 1) >= 960) {
//--------i tried a sample size of 2. was hoping 3 would work---------//
        inSampleSize *= 3;
      }
```

As you can see the first condition does not satisfy, hence while loop is broken and `inSampleSize` remains 1, means image will not be re-sampled. which may cause the OOM.

The idea is, as you go towards the images with higher aspect ratio it will more likely to get OOM with the given condition,

e.g. ,
An image with dimension 2160 x 1035 is more likely to crash your app(note: this image wont re-sample either for the same reason).

And an image with dimension 4320 x 1035 will certainly crash your app(note: this wont re-sample either)

And so does the 1035 x 4320(Portrait case).

So what to change?
   The condition should be modified to make it do something like this,

```
Get the large side of image, down sample it until it fits adjacent device side
```

i'll leave it up to you to change the condition as you may seem fit.

**UPLDATE :**

I would like to state that in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39764102/6035305) answer's comment OP has mentioned link to a gist which really demonstrates what you are looking for. it also goes to extra mile by reducing the size of the given bitmap by setting bitmap configuration to RGB_565 which uses 16 bit per pixel(RGB_888 uses 24).

```
 scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(actualWidth, actualHeight, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
```

*Note that this will reduce the quality of image.*

Comment: Do you have an example of ImageCompression in the gist for me to see?